# Latency in AKS when utilizing Service such as a Load Balancer

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

I'm working on scaling a service using Azure Kubernetes, but I've come across something peculiar.

Here are the results of running Apache Benchmark with 1 pod:

```
Server Software:        nginx/1.16.0
Server Hostname:        demo
Server Port:            80

Document Path:          /
Document Length:        612 bytes

Concurrency Level:      500
Time taken for tests:   1.712 seconds
Complete requests:      10000
Failed requests:        0
Total transferred:      8450000 bytes
HTML transferred:       6120000 bytes
Requests per second:    5842.36 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       85.582 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       0.171 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          4821.09 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        2   36   6.1     36      73
Processing:     9   47   9.1     46      73
Waiting:        1   35   8.1     33      55
Total:         48   84   8.2     83     121

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%     83
  66%     86
  75%     88
  80%     90
  90%     94
  95%     97
  98%    101
  99%    103
 100%    121 (longest request)
```

And here are the results of running Apache Benchmark with 4 pods:

```
Server Software:        nginx/1.16.0
Server Hostname:        demo
Server Port:            80

Document Path:          /
Document Length:        612 bytes

Concurrency Level:      500
Time taken for tests:   2.537 seconds
Complete requests:      10000
Failed requests:        0
Total transferred:      8450000 bytes
HTML transferred:       6120000 bytes
Requests per second:    3941.67 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       126.850 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       0.254 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          3252.65 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        3   51  13.4     52     136
Processing:    19   73  24.3     66     171
Waiting:        1   55  23.0     49     148
Total:         59  125  25.2    121     219

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%    121
  66%    130
  75%    137
  80%    141
  90%    152
  95%    179
  98%    195
  99%    207
 100%    219 (longest request)
```

The question is, why is the "Requests per second" lower with 4 pods compared to 1 pod, and why is the "Time per request" increasing?

Comment: When we increase the no of Pods that are behind a Load Balancer, LB will distribute the overall traffic to all pods which will result in Low "Requests per Second" for the Pods. Same case when there are multiple Pods they compete for resource allocation such as CPU and memory which can also sometimes result in increased latency and decreased throughput.

Answer (score 0):

The `Requests per second` is lower with 4 pods compared to 1 pod, and the `Time per request` is increasing because the service is now handling more requests concurrently. When you have only 1 pod, the service can handle a limited number of requests at a time. As a result, the service can process requests faster, resulting in a higher `Requests per second` and a lower `Time per request`.

However, when you have 4 pods, the service can handle more requests concurrently. This increased concurrency can lead to a higher `Time per request` because the service now has to divide its resources among more requests. The `Requests per second` is also lower because the service is now handling more requests concurrently. This increased load can slow down the service, resulting in a lower `Requests per second`.

To improve the performance of your application, you can try the following:

1. Use a pod autoscaler to ensure that the pods are evenly scheduled across the nodes in the cluster.
2. Use resource requests and limits to ensure that the pods have the resources they need.
3. Use a high-performance load balancer such as such as Azure Application Gateway. The load balancer is responsible for distributing traffic between your pods, so it's important to use a load balancer that is capable of handling the amount of traffic you expect to receive.

Reference:

[AKS Latency](https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/1373)

[Reduce latency in AKS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/reduce-latency-ppg)

[Improve the performance of your AKS cluster](https://stackify.com/aks-cluster-performance-how-to-better-operate-kubernetes-in-azure/)

[AKS best practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/best-practices)